# Dynamic list creation using extra button

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

I want to create a dynamic list.

It can be select option or dropdown or any other list type.

I want to be able to add new options if the current list does not include the desired option.

I want to use a separate button which pops up a new field which allows the user to add a new value to the list.

How can I do that?

[The blue coloured part of this picture shows some code which is producing a pop up in background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkKBx.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see why this question is currently off topic. HINT:Show effort and code in a [mcve]

Comment: No one is going to work of a picture of your code. Add your code to your question so people can help you.

Comment: Sorry for that. I will do next time and will post current one in time.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery 
give a class name to your select and input box and to button then

```
$(".your button class").click(function(){
    var op=$(".your input class").val();
    var data="&lt;option&gt;"+op+"&lt;/option&gt;";
    $(".your select class").append(data);
});
```

Comment: Why use a class name? Just curious to why not use an ID since you would only want to select one element...

Comment: Somehow I got it as I used a modal on the pop up to show my field to be added later. Thank you everyone.

Comment: If we try through any alert type queries it will show in background not on the pop up itself.